# After calling scrollTop, web page always goes up a little then goes down to the right position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery `scrollTop` to scroll the web page to the right position, but the page goes up a little then goes down to the right position in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox. How can I make the web page go to the right position directly?

```
// scrollId is a div
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + scrollId).offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Comment: use the document object instead maybe? `$(document).scrollTop();`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]